# Icon for File app no longer showing

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files, desktop, icons

No more than two/three days ago, the icon for the File app (file manager) is no longer shown, and the icon with the wheen is shown.

Can I recover the correct icon, someway?

Comment: Are you running Juno?  Have you changed the theme? You should have icons for 'system-file-manager.svg' installed.   By 'icon with wheel' I assume you mean the icon for a generic executable i.e. a grey rectangle with an inscribed cog wheel?  Is just in the dock that you are missing the icon or also in the applications menu and app store?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Juno and didn't change the theme.

Yes, that's the icon, the grey rectangle with the wheen inside. I see that icon in the dock and inside the application menu, but I can see the correct icon in  the app store.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the icon name in the file `/usr/share/applications/io.elementary.files.desktop` has been translated in some locales for some reason. If you are in a locale where the translation has changed the icon name (at present [ca] and [it]) then it will cause this problem.

I will file an issue against the project.

Comment: I'm using the italian locale.

Comment: I just noticed the "Multitasking View" (Vista Multitaking in italian) icon has the same problem.

Comment: One more thing I noticed (I don't know if it's related to the first problem): file associations were lost (and if I try to associate, for instance, a json file to Visual Studio Code instead of Code, the choice isn't saved) and, also, folder/file colors are no longer shown (and I can no longer assign them).

Comment: There is an outstanding bug regarding color tags in the latest release - fix has been merged into the source and should be released soon.  An bug report about the file association problem was recently filed.

Comment: The icon issue appears to be a problem with some translators not realising that icon names should not (generally) translated (although for some reason the desktop file specification states that they are localised strings) so it is not actually a bug in Files

Comment: As italian (like the OP probably), I confirm 'Files' and 'Multitask view' icons are missing with a clean install + apt-update&upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AppEditor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/) app from the AppCenter.

In the `AppEditor` search for your app click the icon and choose from available icons. See if that works.

Comment: It didn't work: I installed the app, searched for File and changed it's icon with system-file-manager icon, and the correct icon appeared in the preview but, as son as I clicked the save button, the icon desappeared again from the preview and nothing changed to the dock and appmenu icons.

Comment: Ok so I changed my system locale language to italian and the icon was missing.
I then opened Files as administrator went to /usr/share/applications.
Opened the io.elementary.files.desktop with Code.

Find the line Name[it]=File it should be at line 19 and change the name from File to Files.

Logout from your session, login and try to unpin and pin again to dock the file app.

Comment: Updating---While this method it did  work with Files app it didn't work with multitasking view.

Answer (score 0):

It's a translation error, as Jeremy said. To fix it, edit the file `/usr/share/applications/io.elementary.files.desktop` as sudo (e.g. `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/io.elementary.files.desktop` in the terminal). Look for the line that says `Icon[it]=gestore-di-file-di-sistema` and replace it with `Icon[it]=system-file-manager`.

I had the same problem in Catalan and this fixed it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx.
Funny thing: the update just released had partially fixed the issue. The File icon already in the dock got ok after the update, but the one in the application menu didn't (and neither the multitasking view). I added the File icon to the dock again and the problem reappeared in the dock, too.

Comment: There's clearly some problem with the italian localization: I've just been notified of an update for the code app and the icon in the store was wrong (again the wheel...), but the one in the app menu is correct...

Comment: There are similar problems with the Catalan one (which is the one I use). I had to manually edit the desktop entry of the multitasking view so that the correct icon would appear, same with Files now. I hope devs will fix this eventually!